# Grouping by day in LINQ without TruncateTime()

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have the following LINQ query for a MySQL database in a C# Razor MVC project.

```
private Dictionary<DateTime?, int> getOrderQuantityDict(DateTime start, DateTime end, int siteCode)
{
    return (from o in thisDataEntities.this_table
        where o.created_at >= start
        && o.created_at <= end
        && o.store_id == siteCode
        select new { OrderDate = o.created_at, Id = o.entity_id})
        .GroupBy(q => q.OrderDate)
        .ToDictionary(q => q.Key, q => q.Count());
}
```

I need to group by day. Right now q.OrderDate has hours, minutes, and seconds. I need to ignore those when grouping.

The tricky part: I need to do this without `TruncateTime()`. When our host moved our DB, we lost the ability to use `TruncateTime()` for some reason. Our host has been less than helpful on this issue, and I'm hoping a workaround is possible.

Comment: You could try: `.GroupBy(q => q.OrderDate.Date)`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - I afraid Linq to Entities will not be able to convert property `.Date` to the SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but the following may help you:

```
return (from o in thisDataEntities.this_table
    where o.created_at >= start
    && o.created_at <= end
    && o.store_id == siteCode
    select new { OrderDate = o.created_at, Id = o.entity_id})
    .AsEnumerable() //Once this is executed, the database will return the result of the query and any other statement after this will be ran locally so TruncateTime will not be an issue
    .GroupBy(q => q.OrderDate)
    .ToDictionary(q => q.Key, q => q.Count());
```

Comment: There's a few minor details wrong, but the idea of using `.AsEnumerable()` to allow me to run C# logic was absolutely key. I'll suggest an edit that matches what I used. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert date to the string and make grouping based on the string representation of date.

```
return 
    thisDataEntities.this_table
                    .Where(o => o.created_at >= start)
                    .Where(o => o.created_at <= end)
                    .Where(o => o.store_id == siteCode)
                    .Select(o => new
                            {
                                OrderDate = o.created_at, 
                                Id = o.entity_id,
                                OrderDateFormatted = 
                                    SqlFunctions.DateName("yyyy", o.created_at) + "-" +
                                    SqlFunctions.DateName("mm", o.created_at) + "-" +
                                    SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", o.created_at)
                            })
                    .GroupBy(n => n.OrderDateFormatted) // format "2017-10-03"
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.First().OrderDate, g => g.Count());
```

With approach above execution should happened on database side. Of course only in case `GroupBy` supported.